# Report not showing in IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this code below for showing a report in IFrame

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialogGenerateGL">
<div>
    <iframe id="frmGLs" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 2px solid black; margin: 10px auto;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#Button").click(function(){
 var url = url;
 $("#dialogGenerateGL").dialog("open");
 $("#frmGLs").attr('src', url);
});


$("#dialogGenerateGL").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true
 });
```

As I click the button only the dialogbox is showing.

Comment: @JaromandaX don't worry about the URL. I just state just like that. Sorry for it.

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX no. My console is clear. The first that i check is the dev tool.

Comment: `var url = url;` makes very little sense. Do this: `var url = "http://domain.com/path/to/the/report.html"`

Comment: @zer00ne this is my url `var url = "../Controller/Report?&id=" + applicationId + "&balance=" + balance + "&isAdditionalBenefit=" + isAdditionalBenefit + "&isDraft=" + isDraft + "&signatoryId=" + approvingId + "&signatoryPosition=" + approvingPosition`

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw I got it working take a look at my answer, that mess you showed me just needs to be contacted into **one string**. BTW, if I put that url in, it will fail because you are giving me a relative url, I need an absolute url: `http://domain.com/path/to/the/report.html` otherwise you should do what I suggest on your side because that relative url applies to you not me.

Comment: @zer00ne my brain is going crazy why my code is not working :(

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw each of those parameters are necessary? As it stands you need a value for some unknown variables (at least to me): applicationId, balance, isAdditionalBenefit, isDraft, approvingId, approvingPosition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128902/discussion-between-trafalgar-d-law-and-zer00ne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `var url = 'http://domain.com/path/to/the/report.html'` It works now, see Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var url = 'http://example.com/';
  $("#dialogGenerateGL").dialog("open");
  $("#frmGLs").attr('src', url);
});


$("#dialogGenerateGL").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id='btn1'>Dialog</button>
<div id="dialogGenerateGL">
  <div>
    <iframe id="frmGLs" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 2px solid black; margin: 10px auto;">
    </iframe>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AS you say only your dialog box is showing,because you are calling to the dialog box before adding the url to the iframe.

To resolve this you first need to add the url to iframe then call to the dialog box .

That is

```
 $("#Button").click(function(){
  var url = url;
  $("#frmGLs").attr('src', url);
  $("#dialogGenerateGL").dialog("open");
 });
```

Comment: In var url ,one url must be present.
Ok
Your problem is solved or not ?

Comment: its okay now. Thanks.